# get all rows in common

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database of players and their games. I'm trying to get a list of games, that a set of given players have in common.

Example data:

```
PLAYER  GAME
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       B
2       C
3       B
4       A
4       B
5       C
5       B
```

So, given: `1, 2, 3, 4` it would give me

```
GAME
B
```

And given: `1, 2, 5` it would give me

```
GAME
B
C
```

Comment: When you are providing your given values, what do you mean given?  Is it a users inputted list of player values?  Also, share what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
with cte as (
    select PLAYER, GAME from your_table where  player in (1, 2, 3, 4)
)
select GAME from cte
group by GAME
having count(distinct PLAYER) = (select count(distinct PLAYER) from cte)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I was trying to do something similar based on Gurwinder Singh's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

For 1, 2, 3, 4:

```
select game
from your_table
group by game
having count(distinct case when player in (1, 2, 3, 4) then player end) = 4;
```

For 1, 2, 5:

```
select game
from your_table
group by game
having count(distinct case when player in (1, 2, 5) then player end) = 3;
```

[Demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/YHEEO44958)

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple WHERE clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT game
FROM table_name
WHERE player in (1, 2, 3, 4);

SELECT DISTINCT game
FROM table_name
WHERE player in (1, 2, 5);
```

Edit: added the DISTINCT keyword to the queries, per Gurwinder Singh's comment.

Comment: It's not that simple. See this demo of your queries - http://rextester.com/PTMJ60117

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Not sure what I was thinking - thank you for pointing that out. =)